# How do you preventing a querytable from being deleted when you clear the contents of the querytable?

Tags: excel, vba, database-connection

I use the following:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.ClearContents
```

to clear the contents of a querytable, but the querytable is also deleted. It seems the above code has the same effect as:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Delete
Selection.ClearContents
```

How can I not delete the querytable so that the query can be refreshed later if needed?

Comment: @braX Thanks for your response. I would like to keep the format. If I delete it, the format will also be deleted. Since this is in a tool for others, I want to keep the querytable so the user does not have to create the table again when he/she uses the tool.

Comment: The querytable was initially created using the Data/Get Data menu. Because the query involves some manipulations of the dataset, I cannot use a vba code to perform the query. This is why I need to keep the querytable and refresh it  when needed. I could simply save the data in the file. But since the dataset is large, the file will be very large.

Comment: @braX QueryTables are alive and well. I find them generally expensive but there are good use cases (e.g. I find they are faster for handling v large datasets from SQL Server than creating an ADODB connection and R/W recordset via VBA). They are a fundamental of even the more recent Power tooling.

Answer (score 1):

You are converting to connection only. Instead, target the ListObject databody range

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DeleteData()

    Dim qt As QueryTable

    Set qt = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects(1).QueryTable 'change as required

    Dim deleteRange As Range
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set deleteRange = qt.ListObject.DataBodyRange
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not deleteRange Is Nothing Then
        deleteRange.Delete
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works! I just found out that I could also use ActiveSheet.Rows("2:" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).ClearContents. It is not ideal since the column headers remained.